# Arrayformula is expanding on the whole column besides the the referenced cell being blank through not(isblank)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

What i want is that if someone fills in the google form with dog boarding, google sheets should find the value for that particular service and display. I am using the array formula, with a condition that if the row doesn't have any answer then keep it blank.

Besides that it is expanding to the whole column.

```
=arrayformula(if(not(isblank(I3:I)),index(Sheet2!$B$2:$E$5,match($I$3:$I,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,0),match($D$3:$D,Sheet2!$B$1:$E$1,0)),""))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I3:I="",,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(I3:I)), INDEX(Sheet2!B2:E5, 
 MATCH(I3:I, Sheet2!A2:A5, 0), 
 MATCH(D3:D, Sheet2!B1:E1, 0)), )))
```